# How do I know if a AGP Graphic Card will work with my Dell 4100 System?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, graphics-card, agp

My Dell 4100 system (built in 2001) has a AGP.
Should I be concerned that a newer AGP graphic card will not work in this older system?

Here are two AGP graphic cards sold at our local Microcenter

1. [Radeon HD 3650 512MB DDR2 AGP Graphics Card](http://www.microcenter.com/single_product_results.phtml?product_id=0298243) ($100)
2. [Radeon 9550 256MB DDR AGP 4X/8X Graphics Card](http://www.microcenter.com/single_product_results.phtml?product_id=0311624) ($70)

Will these work in my system? It mentions a lot of **Product Specifications** that I am not sure if they are system specific (i.e. **Interface**, **Memory Bus**, etc.).

The 3650 also mentions that a PCI-E 6-pin power connector is needed. How do I know if I have this power connector?

I just upgraded the Dell 4100 to use Windows 7 RTM and the card in it now does not support Aero along with it producing choppy video playback using Windows Media Player.

I am mainly looking at just getting this system to play the Video back with it not being choppy. Will these two graphics work to do that (If they both will I will buy the cheaper one.)

The Dell 4100 system specifications are:

- 1 ghz
- 512 mb RAM
- 1 agp slots, multiple PCI slots

Here is another tid bit. I read that Windows 7 uses DirectX (or Direct3D) 10.1 and the 3650 mentioned above supports 10.1, where the 9550 supports only 9.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the 3650 needs a PCI-E 6 pin power adapter, I would bet your Power Supply doesn't have it. There are adapters for this, however. ([link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812200106&cm_re=6_pin_adapter-_-12-200-106-_-Product))

I'm pretty sure with AGP that if a card is AGP and you have an AGP slot, you should be fine, as long as the x# matches with your system's specs. (don't quote me, though :) )

But, check with Micro Center's return policy. If it doesn't work, you may be able to return it. Also, *definitely* check with a sales associate at the store and tell them about your machine. They will know for sure if your machine can handle it.

As for DirectX, yes, Windows 7 uses DX 10 and eventually DX 11. By no means is this necessary (especially for your older machine). There are only a handful of games that even support DX 10 at this point, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.